# Convert rows to columns in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssms-2014

I'm posting the query below which I used to retrieve the data and output how it shows and how do I need also .. please let me know how can I convert rows to columns data

Comment: This is known as a pivot. It has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times. Do you always have the same columns or are they dynamic?

Comment: I have same Facility_MisFacID,data same many times

Comment: Meaning the columns are always going to be the same?

Comment: Yes sean its going to be same

Comment: Are you working on this one @SeanLange

Comment: @SeanLange i have somethink i like now                                               
      Measure    no of TotalPatients   no of Soundpatients Lengt ofStay
      CLABSI abc1234563                    Tcremes               7
      MRSA abc8456957                    Jyuiwn                       9
      MRSA abc8523694                   Dsreram              17
      CLABSI abc7456898                   Tcremes              17
      MRSA abc9852367                   Jyuiwn                       7
      MRSA abc7874945                  Rcrekiws               9

Comment: I have no idea what that means. If it is relevant to your question you should edit your question. Comments are horrible for formatting.

Comment: its kind of similar only , but not related to  above question . that's why I posted in link with exact screenshot where I have written everything on that screenshot

Comment: you can go to this link to see my question,I'm limited to post questions today  
 type in google https then :// and then followup with imgur and dot com/a/XbwlgJq

Comment: In the above comment you can see my link @SeanLange..If i post whole link it will not let you see it so i formatted it to words

Comment: If you have a new question you should start a new question here.

Comment: @SeanLange I need to wait few days to ask question again here, Pleas help me sean

Comment: Did you get a question ban or something? Sorry but I don't get paid for this and spending a bunch of time piecing together a question is not in the cards.

Comment: Yes i have a question ban

Comment: Make your next one better and you won't get banned. :) Post ddl and sample data. Make it easy for others to help. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: CAST(ISNULL(t.SSN,' ') AS CHAR(20))  +
  CAST(ISNULL(t.Number,' ') AS VARCHAR(20))  +

Comment: @SeanLange How do i put comma after ssn in the above query .. im getting result as            
 123-45-6789001234 , but i need it to be as 123-45-6789,001234

Comment: Seriously....just stop. I am not going to spend a bunch of time unravelling data and requirements for a different question from comments. And for the sake of anything sane please don't ever store SSN in clear text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation since the columns are constant.

```
select
    BarCdmID
    , AME = MAX(case when Facility_MisFacID = 'AME' then MyCount end) 
    , AMV = MAX(case when Facility_MisFacID = 'AMV' then MyCount end) 
    , BHV = MAX(case when Facility_MisFacID = 'BHV' then MyCount end) 
    , BRV = MAX(case when Facility_MisFacID = 'BRV' then MyCount end) 
    , EOR = MAX(case when Facility_MisFacID = 'EOR' then MyCount end) 
    , IPA = MAX(case when Facility_MisFacID = 'IPA' then MyCount end) 
    , IPB = MAX(case when Facility_MisFacID = 'IPB' then MyCount end) 
    , LTC = MAX(case when Facility_MisFacID = 'LTC' then MyCount end) 
    , OHW = MAX(case when Facility_MisFacID = 'OHW' then MyCount end) 
from
(
    Select BarCdmID = LEFT(BarCdmID, 2)
        , Facility_MisFacID
        , MyCount = count(*)
    from BarCdm_Facil
    group by LEFT(BarCdmID, 2)
        , Facility_MisFacID

) x
group by X.BarCdmID
order by BarCdmID
```

Comment: received the below error.  Column 'X.BarCdmID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I will fix that in a second but seriously if you can't find that I am concerned that you will just use this code and not understand what it is doing.

Comment: Please help me with this one .. I have attached a screenshot how it looks in result set and how I need also link here  ...  https://imgur.com/a/XbwlgJq

Answer (score 0):

you should use pivot when you want to convert rows to column base on one column

```
    ( select left(BarCdmID,2) as BarCdmID ,
[0] as AME,
[1] as AMV, 
[2] as BHV ,
[3] as BRV,
[4] as EOR ,
[5] as IPA,
[6] as IPB,
[7] as LTC,
[8] as OHW from BARCDM_FACIL) T
    pivot 
(facility_misfacID
 FOR T.BarCdmID 
IN [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]
    ) as pvt
```